# Object Detection API error: "ImportError: cannot import name anchor_generator_pb2"

Tags: tensorflow, importerror, object-detection

I'm trying to get Tensorflow's new [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) working. I've followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md), but when running the command

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I get the following error

```
from object_detection.protos import anchor_generator_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name anchor_generator_pb2
```

I've looked inside [object_detection.protos](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection/protos), and there doesn't seem to be anything named anchor_generator_pb2. Has anyone else managed to get this command to run, or solved this issue?

Comment: Thanks, finally got this working along with help from `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2930`

Answer (score 15):

Missed a step in the installation instructions, where the following needs to be run from `models/research`:

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

You need to rerun the below command after that:

```
pip install .
```

Comment: After that i had to rerun "pip install ." in research directory

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
Run it from your `models/research`

```
python setup.py
protoc -I=./ --python_out=./ ./object_detection/protos/*.proto
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```