# Cannot run Object Detector issues on Windows (ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos')

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, protoc

I'm trying to setup the tensorflow OD package and I tried installing it from the repo, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I followed the installation steps ([object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md#python-package-installation)) and tried running the test files `object_detection.builders.model_builder_tf2_test.py` with no avail.

1. The `protoc` executable is not recognized
2. I got a `tf_utils missing` message at one point
3. And ended up with `ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'`

I'm a novice playing with this tool, has anybody ran into these issues?

I found these related issues and tried several things, but each step I make forward unlocks another issue.

- [Object Detection API error: "ImportError: cannot import name anchor_generator_pb2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972277/object-detection-api-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-anchor-generator-pb#44974014)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2930

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts, starting from a new environment, I put together the steps to make it work.

#### Create Environment from YML

1. Use this barebone setup to create a new environment (see snippet below)
2. Clone the Object Detector (OD) repository

   - Follow instructions here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md#python-package-installation

     - `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git`
3. Download protobuf (google) win64 ZIP

   - https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.15.1/protoc-3.15.1-win64.zip
   - unzip
   - from `bin/` copy `protoc.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32`
   - test by running `protoc` in command prompt
4. Run code below from {rootdir}

   ```
   cd models/research
   # Compile protos.
   protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
   # Install TensorFlow Object Detection API.
   cp object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py .
   # Step below is important even if some comments online (2021-02-23) suggest it is deprecated
   python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
   # The step below was added, after unsuccessful previous attempts, from [this related issue][1]
   pip install .
   ```
5. To validate setup, run either of the following

   - `python object_detection.builders.model_builder_tf2_test.py`
   - `import object_detection.builders.model_builder_tf2_test`

```html
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: win-64
@EXPLICIT
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/ca-certificates-2021.1.19-haa95532_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/vc-14.2-h21ff451_1.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/openssl-1.1.1i-h2bbff1b_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_4.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/sqlite-3.33.0-h2a8f88b_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/python-3.8.0-hff0d562_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/certifi-2020.12.5-py38haa95532_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/wincertstore-0.2-py38_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/setuptools-52.0.0-py38haa95532_0.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/pip-20.3.3-py38haa95532_0.conda
```

Comment: thanks to @sebastian-ax for the useful comment here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972277/object-detection-api-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-anchor-generator-pb#44974014)