# cannot import name 'anchor_generator_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

I am encountering this error --> `cannot import name 'anchor_generator_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'` when I run a verification script. There are a couple of solutions however they don't resolve the error.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44972277/15751564

Comment: I have tried that before, but I get another error: protoc : The term 'protoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For more info: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10706#issuecomment-1184668036